# how to disable clicking of calendar after first click?[edited for solution]

Tags: javascript, ajax, calendar, dhtml

i am using an DHTML calendar in my application.
on clicking a date ,there is a form submit action.

**i want to disable the calendar after first click ,so that user can not click the other date before the form submit.**

my code is

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">

function dateChanged(calendar) 
{
    // Beware that this function is called even if the end-user only
    // changed the month/year. In order to determine if a date was
    // clicked you can use the dateClicked property of the calendar:
    if (calendar.dateClicked) {
    // OK, a date was clicked, redirect to /yyyy/mm/dd/index.php
    var y = calendar.date.getFullYear();
    var m = calendar.date.getMonth() + 1; // integer, 0..11
    var d = calendar.date.getDate(); // integer, 1..31
    var NewDate = y + "-" + m + "-" + d;
    document.getElementById("<?=$mydata[FILTER]?>").value = NewDate;
    submitForm();
}




    var tempDate = new Date(<?=$CalDate?>);
    Calendar.setup({
            flat        : "<?=$mydata[FILTER]?>_show_date",     // ID of the parent element
            flatCallback:dateChanged,                                           // our callback function
            weekNumbers:false,                                              // Don't display week numbers
            date        : tempDate      
                    // Set calendar to start at selected date
        });

    document.getElementById("<?=$mydata[FILTER]?>").value = '<?=$mydata[FILTER]?>';
```

i made a solution for this 
i disabled div and all the children of div
using the code

```
**var nodes = document.getElementById("13-1_show_date").getElementsByTagName('*');
for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++)
{                                               
nodes[i].disabled = true;
}     
submitForm();**
```

this code will disable the div and its childrens after first click.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is a classical problem, and there are many ways:

1. Use a temporary variable called `isClciked` and set it to true in the first click, and in subsequent clicks, check it, and if it's true, then simply `return;`.
2. On the first execution of your click handler, disable the entire calender (this in itself has many ways)

Comment: we can do it .
but the problem is that it should be visible to user that the calendar is disabled and can not be clicked any more till the form get submitted.

Comment: Then simply do that using CSS.

Comment: can you be more clear please.
using css ,how can we block clicks
i dont want to hide the calendar.

Comment: You can add an attribute to the HTML element like `disabled='disabled'` (mimicing browser's behavior), and write a CSS rule to use `opacity: 0.6;` for elements which has this attribute.